# NodeJS and ORM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, django, spring-boot, orm

I have looked and worked with couple of back-end frameworks like django, RoR, Spring Boot. All of them come with a built in ORM.

But NodeJS is popular as others, lacks an inbuilt ORM. What could be the reason behind the lack of built-in ORM?

Comment: You may also consider NodeJS to be like the JDK. That one does not come with built-in ORM either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to compare apples with oranges. NodeJs is a runtime environment. django, RoR and Spring Boot are frameworks.

Searching the internet for NodeJs frameworks with bundled ORMs will return some useful results.

Comment: Would it mean it is more suitable for certain type of loads like gateways? Are there any similar frameworks worth considering in JS?

Comment: How did you get that from what hairmot said? He explicitly said it is *not* a framework; it can be used to *build* frameworks.

Comment: node is useful for applications which require a high number of simultaneous connections with high throughput. It's also useful if you want your entire stack built in the same technology (javascript). There are some existing frameworks such as sails that seem to do what you want, but i've never used them so can't comment!

Comment: Yes I got it, but trying to find other comparable frameworks built using NodeJS.